# DB2 connection failed php

Tags: php, db2

I'm trying to connect to remote DB2 via PHP. But have some problems. I've already installed IBM Application developer client.

phpinfo() output:

```
    
        IBM DB2, Cloudscape and Apache Derby support    enabled
        Module release  1.9.4
        Module revision $Revision: 327944 $
        Binary data mode (ibm_db2.binmode)  DB2_BINARY
```

Then, I've got a php file which is looking like:

```
    
        $database = 'MyDB';
        $user = 'db2inst1';
        $password = 'mypassword';
        $hostname = '1.1.1.1';
        $port = 50000;

        $conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC  DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;PORT=$port;HOSTNAME=$hostname;".
        "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";

        $conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
        if ($conn) {
            echo "connection to $database succeeded";
        } else {
            echo "connection to $database failed";
            echo db2_conn_errormsg();
        }
```

And trying to execute this file, I have "connection to MyDB failed", and NO visible response from db2_conn_errormsg(), which is actually making me baffled

Unfortunately, I haven't got a straight access to the remote server with database. But several months ago, when I was using other client, I succeeded to connect to exactly this database. But that time I didn't need to install IBM ADCL. That is why I can guess that problem is on this side. But even if so, I couldn't fix it.

Sorry if I duplicated some question on stackoverflow, but all answers, which I found, were unfortunately useless to me.

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.
Hope you can help.

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have connectivity to the server? Correct port, server, firewall rules, username, password, database name?

What is the SQL code you are receiving. Try to get the SQL code from PHP, "connection to xx failed" is your own code so it is useless to help you.

Did you install the application development client? which DB2 version are you using? ADCL is old, it was for DB2 8. Since DB2 9.7, clients have different names, and I think you need IBM Data server client in order to compile the php module. For more information, check this website: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

I think you have to catalog the database server (node) and the database in the local machine with the db2 client. It seems that your PHP code uses ODBC driver, and it has to be configured locally.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string looks like an ODBC connection where as the db2_connect function in PHP needs :-

```
DATABASE=database;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=username;PWD=password;
```

It's on the [PHP web page.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get ibm_db2 or pdo_ibm working on a remote. They work if DB2 and Apache are on the same machine (like the iSeries) but not if the host is connecting to a remote DB2.

If you read the Doctrine2 PHP drivers for each you will find they redirect to ODBC if the host is not 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.

This code works for me

```
<?php
if (!$db = odbc_connect ( "AS400", $user, $password) )
    echo 'error!';

$result = odbc_exec($db, "select count(*) from $table");
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
    var_dump($result);
    print_r($result);
    echo "\n";
    echo odbc_result($result, 1)."\n";
}

odbc_close($db);
```

AS400 is DSN name defined in ODBC.